# Bitnami WordPress on Amazon EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I installed the Bitnami WordPress AMI on Amazon EC2 and I'm not sure about a few things. I can not find any documentation about my issues out there.

I'm using the Starkers 2 naked theme and Bitnami ssems to be embedding the CSS in the  instead of linking to the style.css stylesheet.

```
<style id='screen-css' media='screen'>@import url(wp-content/themes/frontier/css/reset.css) ;div,article,section,header,footer,nav,li{position:relative}
```

Then whenever I am working directly on the server via SFTP, my CSS updates are not updating automatically.

Bitnami comes with Varnish caching I believe but it is disabled. Not sure if anyone else experiences these issues.

Comment: Problem seen with any browser?

Comment: All browsers. Cleared cache, incognito. I ended up building a LAMP stack manually, but I'm still confused as to what's causing this.

Comment: Bitnami WordPress ships Varnish server but it is not enabled by default. It has enabled PageSpeed module but it does not seem to be the problem.